# How do I load JSP with Jquery.load() function when the JSP is under WEB-INF folder?

Tags: jquery, jsp

Here's the directory structure that I have in my project

```
WebContent
 --resources
 --WEB-INF
   --classes
   --jsp
     dashboard.jsp
     home.jsp
   --lib
```

I want to load home.jsp inside dashboard.jsp using Jquery method

$("#result").load("home.jsp");

But it is not working. I believe, the way I am referencing my home.jsp page is incorrect in the load method. How do I make a call to home.jsp (from dashboard.jsp) which resides under WEB-INF/jsp folder?

Comment: I think. IF you can run your jsp page in browser then with the same url you can load with jquery.

Comment: When you put the jsp under WEB-INF folder, its inaccessible via url

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments it is not possible to access any file within the WEB-INF folder by url. But you may be able to access it via jsp:include

```
<jsp:include page="WEB-INF/home.jsp" />
```

*(I simply don't know if that works, but it's worth a shot, if appliable)*

The url is always relative to the 'combined' URL (for the lack of a better word). So if you access a .jsp file via a servlet with:

```
request.getRequestDispatcher("/WEB-INF/dashboard.jsp").forward(request, response);
```

the url you reference form is actually the URL of your servlet.

Taking this into account, the URL *would be* `$("#result").load("/WEB-INF/home.jsp")` but since the entire WEB-INF folder is inaccessable from everywhere but Servlets (and then only to dispatch to them), you cannot access home.jsp from jquery.

So to provide a solution to your problem:

Either

- put home.jsp out of the WEB-INF folder,
- create a Servlet that dispatches to it,
- try jsp:include

Comment: <jsp:include page="WEB-INF/home.jsp" /> is not working in .load() function of the jquery.

Answer (score 2):

```
$("#result").load("/home.jsp");
```

Comment: What would be the path name?