# Replace content in div add jsp after successful ajax function

Tags: ajax, jsp

I would like to replace a content of `<div id="container"></div>`  with a jsp page after the ajax function is successful, also without page refresh.

```
$.ajax({
  type: "POST",
  url: "scripts/process.php",
  data: dataString,
  success: function() {
    //Whats the code here to replace content in #conatiner div to:
    //replace with my.jsp
  }
});
return false;
```

Comment: Do you want to replace it with an entire jsp page/html content? Also what is the content of jsp?

Comment: yes,ı want to replace it with  an entire jsp.Jsp includes some html contents

Comment: Are you serving it as file or string content?

Comment: [Try this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15111588/how-do-i-load-jsp-with-jquery-load-function-when-the-jsp-is-under-web-inf-fold) if you haven't yet